# Creating chart in chart.js version 4.3 does not work

Tags: chart.js

I'm using the following chart.js plot (in Javascript):

```
new Chart.Scatter(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: {
         datasets: [{
           data: {{ data }},
           showLine: false,
           borderColor: "blue",
           backgroundColor: "blue"
         }]
    }
});
```

When using `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>` it works well but when I try to switch to the most recent version `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.3.0/chart.min.js"></script>` it does not work anymore.

What do I have to change in the newest version?

Comment: I think in version 4 Chart.js is distributed as module and the files are changed. Can you try to import "chart.min.umd.js". Here the migration guide: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/migration/v4-migration.html

Comment: @user2057925 Do you mean importing through the <script> tag?

Comment: Yes, I usually use <script src="https://npmcdn.com/chart.js@latest/dist/chart.umd.js"></script>

Comment: @user2057925 Unfortunately, it still does not work. It gives the error "Chart is not defined"